# Security risks by hosting a Nextcloud on home PC via virtual server

Tags: webserver

I found this question [I want to host a server from my home computer; safe?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/135003/221990) that indicates that hosting anything connected to the open web on a private is a great security risk. As I am totally new to this topic, I wonder if tunneling the traffic via 6tunnel over a virtual server provided by one of the many options changes anything about security threats and terms of use breach with the ISP. Is that the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say, tunneling traffic using 6tunnel, you are considering security in transit while when you mentioned use of virtual server, you are considering seclusion of private system and server so private data is considered safe.The hardware to serve both remains the same.

The risk you are not considering is comprise of web app/site and the moment control is gained, attacker will know very easily that the system is hosted on which virtualization technology and try to bypass it to gain hold of underlying system via local network or bypassing virtualization layer. These attacks are not theoretical. Even when you consider hosting your site on docker, you need to take care to make docker secure enough before hosting it on internet. A good amount of administration and care is needed to take such calculated risk.

I can only talk about security threats and have little to no idea about which country you belong to, what ISP are you using and what conditions shall be considered for commenting on breach of use with ISP. I request you to consider doing your risk assessment thoroughly again.